# 3D callout line doesn't work with client-side graphics

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am struggling to use callout line with client-side graphics.

I followed [the "Point styles for cities" example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/visualization-point-styles/index.html) which uses a feature layer from [the "LyonPointsOfInterest (FeatureServer)"](http://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/LyonPointsOfInterest/FeatureServer).

But it doesn't work with a feature layer which creates client-side graphics based on data returned from a web service.

Is there a limitation on 3d callout line?

Here's my code snippet:

1. Create a feature layer based on layer definition:

   ```
   featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
     fields: this.layerDefinition.fields,
     objectIdField: this.layerDefinition.objectIdField,
     geometryType: this.layerDefinition.geometryType,
     id: this.layerId
   });
   ```
2. Set elevation and feature reduction and renderer:

   ```
   featureLayer.elevationInfo = {
     // elevation mode that will place points on top of the buildings or other SceneLayer 3D objects
     mode: "relative-to-scene"
   };
   // feature reduction is set to selection because our scene contains too many points and they overlap
   featureLayer.featureReduction = {
     type: "selection"
   };

   featureLayer.renderer = this._getUniqueValueRenderer() as any as Renderer// callout render
   ```
3. Here the renderer code:

   ```
   _getUniqueValueRenderer() {
     let verticalOffset = { // verticalOffset shifts the symbol vertically
       screenLength: 150, // callout line length
       maxWorldLength: 200,
       minWorldLength: 35
     },
     uniqueValueRenderer = {
       type: "unique-value", // autocasts as new UniqueValueRenderer()
       field: "AQHI",
       uniqueValueInfos: [{
         value: 1,
         symbol: this._get3DCallOutSymbol(verticalOffset, "Museum.png", "#D13470")
       }, {
         value: 2,
         symbol: this._get3DCallOutSymbol(verticalOffset, "Restaurant.png", "#F97C5A")
       }, {
         value: 3,
         symbol: this._get3DCallOutSymbol(verticalOffset, "Church.png", "#884614")
       }, {
         value: 4,
         symbol: this._get3DCallOutSymbol(verticalOffset, "Hotel.png", "#56B2D6")
       }, {
         value: 5,
         symbol: this._get3DCallOutSymbol(verticalOffset, "Park.png", "#40C2B4")
       }, {
         value: 6,
         symbol: this._get3DCallOutSymbol(verticalOffset, "Museum.png", "#D13470")
       }, {
         value: 7,
         symbol: this._get3DCallOutSymbol(verticalOffset, "beer.png", "#F97C5A")
       }, {
         value: 8,
         symbol: this._get3DCallOutSymbol(verticalOffset, "senate.png", "#884614")
       }, {
         value: 9,
         symbol: this._get3DCallOutSymbol(verticalOffset, "Hotel.png", "#56B2D6")
       }, {
         value: 10,
         symbol: this._get3DCallOutSymbol(verticalOffset, "Park.png", "#40C2B4")
       }
     ]};
     return uniqueValueRenderer;
   }

   _get3DCallOutSymbol(verticalOffset: any, iconName: string, color: string) {
     return {
       type: "point-3d", // autocasts as new PointSymbol3D()
       symbolLayers: [{
         type: "icon", // autocasts as new IconSymbol3DLayer()
         resource: {
           href: this.iconPath + iconName
         },
         size: 20,
         outline: {
           color: "white",
           size: 2
         }
       }],
       verticalOffset: verticalOffset,
       callout: {
         type: "line", // autocasts as new LineCallout3D()
         color: "white",
         size: 2,
         border: {
           color: color
         }
       }
     };
   }
   ```
4. Set source to an array of graphics, generated based web service data

   ```
   featureLayer.source = graphics;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `this.layerDefinition` in the instanciation a your new FeatureLayer, but put it in a new var. Idem for `this.layerId` :

```
var layerDef = this.layerDefinition;
var lyrId = this.layerId;
featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
  fields: layerDef.fields,
  objectIdField: layerDef.objectIdField,
  geometryType: layerDef.geometryType,
  id: lyrId
});
```

because `this.` at this place, is in the scope of `new Feature()`